# The page does not display information about created links in the admin panel. Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

The page should display a **feedback form** and **links** created in the admin panel. Created models:

```
from django.db import models

class ContactModel(models.Model):
    # feedback form
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    website = models.URLField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.email}'

class ContactLink(models.Model):
    # links
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to='icons/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I connected the models to the admin panel:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ContactModel, ContactLink

@admin.register(ContactModel)
class ContactModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'create_at']
    list_display_links = ('name',)

admin.site.register(ContactLink)
```

Everything works correctly, you can create links in the admin panel.

Below `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import ContactLink


class ContactView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        contacts = ContactLink.objects.all()
        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {'contact': contacts, 'form': form})
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('feedback/', views.CreateContact.as_view(), name='feedback'),  
]
```

I go through the `for` loop through the code to return **links** from the admin panel:

```
#links
<div class="contact__widget">
    <ul>
        {% for contact in contacts %}                       
            <li>
                <img src="{{ contact.icon.url }}">
                <span>{{ contact.name }}</span>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}             
   </ul>
</div>

#feedback form
<form action="{% url 'feedback' %}" method="post">
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="site-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**The Feedback form** works fine, but **links** are not displayed at all on the page... Where could the error be?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrB4S.png)

Comment: Try using {% for contact in contacts.all %} when iterating through contacts.

Comment: @Marco did not help.  No changes.

Comment: You must use `'contacts': contacts` instead of `'contact': contacts`.

Comment: @Marco it works. Write an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view must reference to the correct variable name. Use `contact` with an `s` in:

```
return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', {'contacts': contacts, 'form': form})
```